# Pass Data Between Controllers in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, controller, global-variables

I have a view on my Laravel website that displays some products. When a user clicks on a product, they are taken to that specific product page. On each specific product page, there is an "order" button. When the user clicks on the "order" button, they are taken to a checkout page only for that specific product where they clicked the "order" button. The controller below handles showing all products and single products.

ProductController:

```
public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::get();

        return view('products.products')->with('products', $products);
    }

    public function show($slug)
    {
        $product = Product::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

        return view('products.product')->with('product', $product);
    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('products', 'ProductController@index')->name('products');
Route::get('products/{product}', 'ProductController@show')->name('product');

Route::get('order', 'OrderController@create')->name('order')->middleware('verified');
Route::post('order', 'OrderController@order')->name('order');
```

I have a separate controller to handle the order page. How can I pass the data of the specific product into the order controller/view?

Comment: This is probably too broad of a question in its current form for Stackoverflow. You need to look into how Sessions work (persisting data between pages), a Cart system, etc etc; all staples of eCommerce.

Comment: I don’t want to use a cart system because my website doesn’t exactly work like a normal e-commerce site. Users can only place one order for one product at a time. I just would like to know how I can pass a single variable between 2 controllers.

Comment: Oh ok, that's no so bad. I think you'd likely still use a Session; when you land on `products/{product}`, set that product in session (like `session()->put('orderProduct', $product);`, then when you land on `order`, reference it: `session()->get('orderProduct');`. That's an overview of the approach, more info can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session

Comment: Yeah, I looked into that, although I wasn’t sure that was the correct way of doing it. However, I will try to implement the use of session now that you have recommended it. Are you sure there isn’t an easier way to do this?

Comment: Yeah, an argument could be made that it's a little redundant to use `session()` for a single product. You could always reference the product directly in the URL, like `/order/product/{product}`, but I'd say either way is fine.

Comment: You would want to use session should you want to have a separate link on the website for user to click back to the "order" page.

Comment: My perspective on the matter: Each product record in the db table should have a product identifier (like _product_id_ for example). In the template file `products.product`, the product details (returned by `ProductController::show`) should be displayed in a form (with a `form` tag). Its action should be an url pointing to the specific method of `OrderController` (the one handling the `onclick` event of the _"Order"_ button; let's say it's `OrderController::create`) and having the product identifier as _parameter_.

Comment: Something like `order/create/2673` (with product id beeing 2673). When the _"Order"_ button is clicked, the form is submitted and `OrderController::create` is called. The product id (2673) is passed as argument to it. The method then fetches only the product details needed for creating an order, based only on the provided product id (2673). _P.S_: I hope I understood right what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

ProductController:

```
public function show($slug)
    {
        $product= Product::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
        Session::put('product', $product);

        return view('products.product')->with('product', $product);
    }
```

OrderController:

```
public function create()
    {
        $product = Session::get('product');
        
        return view('user.order')->with('product', $product);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

This is so simple, Just pass the product id to the other controller via route.
and then you can do anything you want in order controller.